# How does Azuma's Inequality result from Pinelis Inequality?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, inequalities

According to [1]

> Let $(\mathcal{X},||\cdot||)$ be a separable Banach space and let
>   $S(\mathcal{X})$ denote the class of all sequences
>   $f=(f_j)=(f_0,f_1,...)$ of Bochner-integrable random vectors in
>   $\mathcal{X}$, with $f_0=0$ defined on a probability space
>   $(\Omega,F,P)$.
>
> For $f\in S(\mathcal{X})$, put $f^*=\sup\{||f_j||,j=0,1,...\}$, $d_0=d_0(f_0)$, $d_j=d_j(f)=f_j-f_{j-1}$. $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})$ denotes the class of all sequences $(f_j)\in S(\mathcal{X})$ that are martingales.

Theorem 3 says:

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{ess} \sup ||d_n||^2\leq1$, and either $\mathcal{X}\in D(A_1,A_2)$ or $\mathcal{X}=L^p,p\leq 2$. Then
>   \begin{align}
> P(f^*\geq r) \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2B}\right), r \leq 0,\quad (1)
> \end{align}
>   where $B=A_1^2+A_2$ for $\mathcal{X}\in D(A_1,A_2)$ and $B=p-1$ for $\mathcal{X}=L^p$.

I am interested in the following statement:

> In the case $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}$, Theorem 3 is another result due to Hoeffding (1963), often ascribed to Azuma (1967).

This is not clear to me at all how [Azuma's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality) follows from this. I could set $f_j=\sum_{i=1}^jX_i$, which is clearly a martingal and $d_j=X_j$, however even if $X_j\in[a_j,b_j]$, the assumption $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{ess} \sup ||d_n||^2\leq1$ does not hold.

Furthermore, the left hand side of Eq. (1) would be
$$
P\left(\sup\left\{||\sum_{i=1}^nX_i||,n=0,1,...\right\} \geq r\right)
$$

[1] [An Approach to Inequalities for the Distributions of Infinite-Dimensional Martingales, Iosif Pinelis](http://books.google.de/books?id=_qGsljjxgsUC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=pinelis+an+approach+to+inequalities+for+the&source=bl&ots=RCKr4SGZn5&sig=fCs_zRA_1ncFTginpX2_1DeO8nY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ryRjVPe0LNjtaOu9gfAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed integer $n$, we consider $d_j=X_j$ if $j\leqslant n$ and $d_j=0$ otherwise. If $|X_j|\leqslant r_j$ almost surely, then we have 
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mathrm{ess\,sup}\lVert X_j\rVert^2\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^nc_j^2=:c$, hence we use the result with $d'_j:=d_j/c$ and $r':=r/c$.